# SQL - How to get total number of partitions of table via code

Tags: sql, ssms

I am trying to find a way to get the total number of partitions on a table, but I am having trouble doing that via code.

I know I can see the value by going Table Properties > Storage

[image: Table Properties Storage Tab]

Is there a way to get this via code?

Answer (score 0):

This info comes from [sys.dm_db_partition_stats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-partition-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
SELECT  
    MAX(PS.partition_number) AS PartitionCount
FROM
    sys.dm_db_partition_stats PS
WHERE
    PS.index_id = 1 --The parttion scheme is using a Clustered Index
```